# How do I extract Export Table from PE standard (.exe)

Tags: c++, portable-executable

I've managed to successfully extract all desired information from the "Optional Header". All those contained within the "Standard" fields and "Windows-specific" fields. However when it came to the "Data Directories" field, I found the values contained within the "Export Table" field were equal to zero.

How can I locate the "Export Table" within the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to DeadMG's answer: the question's title indicates that you're using an EXE file. You will find that most EXEs do not have export tables, since they are not "consumed" by other components. Most often, they act as consumers for other DLLs. EXE files usually import other DLLs, and these DLLs may have non-empty export sections.

Answer (score 1):

The export table is optional- not every executable has one. You may just find that a sample PE file doesn't have one.

Comment: I'm using Frhed as my Hex Editor and I found an export table containing dll's and function calls. But I want to locate that through lookup and not through extensive search.

Comment: If what you found contains a list of DLLs and function calls, could it be the import table (rather than the export table)? The export table, if it exists, contains only a single module name.